# Suppress warning dialog when updating chart links in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm working on a macro to automatically update all of the linked charts in a presentation from their source Excel workbooks. My problem is that when the linked workbook cannot be found, executing the `LinkFormat.Update` method produces the standard "The linked file is not available...." dialog. This could result in the user having to dismiss the dialog dozens or even hundreds of times when updating a presentation.

Is there any way to suppress this dialog when updating a linked chart, either directly or by verifying the link source before attempting an update? The operation does not produce an error, so it can't be trapped. I'm using `Chart.ChartData.IsLinked` to check for and filter out charts that aren't linked at all, but I can't find any similar property or method that would allow me to check the status of an existing link before executing `LinkFormat.Update`. I would expect that setting `Application.DisplayAlerts` to `ppAlertsNone` would work, but `ppAlertsNone` is already the default, and setting it manually has no effect.

Comment: Try with `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` maybe.

Comment: I just tried that and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linked shapes will be of type msoLinkedOLEObject or msoLinkedPicture (which you probably aren't concerned with).  A linked shape's .LinkFormat.SourceFullname will give you the full path to the linked file, so something like this should get you going.  The test for existence of the file's simplistic but it's a starting point:

```
For Each oSh In ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes
    If oSh.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then
        If Len(Dir$(oSh.LinkFormat.SourceFullName)) > 0 Then
            ' do your thing
        End If
    End If
Next
```